# value of input field is one character behind

Tags: javascript, jquery, text, input

Morning,

When logging my input field the character is always one character behind. When my value field contains 'foo', my logs tells me 'fo'.

Any toughts?

Not much code to show but:
(code example is with on-change, i tried it with keyup, keydown, .. same result.

```
$('#list_search').on('change', searchForBurger);

function searchForBurger(e){
  console.log($(this).val());
}
```

Thx in advance.

Comment: Works fine here _http://jsfiddle.net/dD5yQ/_

Comment: the result which you were saying can seen when `keydown` event is used. I think you forgot to clear the cache of your browser.

Comment: Thats no live update, so it doesn't do what i need.

Comment: Mr_Green clearing my cache has no effect.

Comment: `$('#list_search').on('keyup', searchForBurger);`

Comment: Please read what i put above LightStyle, i allready tested it with keyup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
 $(function(){
   $('#list_search').on('keyup', searchForBurger);
 });
 function searchForBurger(e){
    alert($(this).val());
 }

 <input type="text" id="list_search" />
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/R3Z7z/)

Comment: That works indeed, but it doesn't at my project. The content is dynamically loaded (ajax). Perhaps that has something to do with it?

Comment: 2 years later, I solute you.

Comment: 10 years later, I was facing an issue with keydown not detecting a single character in val(), never expected it to change when I used keyup!
Thanks a million